# Finding the domain a domain controller belongs to

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

How do I figure out the name of the domain a domain controller belongs to?

For example I have the domain controller `\\nFS01.nfs01.local`. It says the domain of this is NFS0101 but I don't remember setting a domain name like that, so is there a way to find this information out for another domain such as another controller with the name `\\fs01.local`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a command prompt on the DC run "set" and look at the USERDNSDOMAIN and USERDOMAIN environment variables to get the DNS and NetBIOS names of the domain.

Answer (score 3):

Open PowerShell on a domain controller.

Run:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  
Get-ADDomain | select DNSRoot,NetBIOSName
```

This will output the FQDN of your domain and the NetBIOS name.

Or, just open the Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in. It's right at the top in the left-hand pane.